# Using the fundamental theorem of calculus part 1

Tags: calculus

Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ if $y = \Big( \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} (t^3+1)^{10} dt \Big)^3$.

My try at the answer:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 3\cdot \Big( \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} (t^3+1)^{10} dt \Big)^2 \cdot ( x^3+1)^{10}$

I'm using chain rule here. Would that be the correct way to go about this? Also, how would you evaluate the integral $\Big( \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} (t^3+1)^{10} dt \Big)^2$?

Comment: You had an extra factor of $3x^2$ that doesn't belong there (now removed). Remember that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(x)\,dx = f(x)$. As to the integral, it's a polynomial, it should be straightforward to integrate.

Comment: Your calculation is correct.  I would leave it as it is; I doubt you're expected to evaluate the integral and then square it.  The whole point of the problem is that it's unnecessary to do so in order to compute the derivative.

Comment: I just realized that and fixed it. I wasn't sure how keep going with the other integral in the final answer.

Comment: You could just leave it as is (I expect this is meant to be an application of the FTC, rather than integration practice), as saulspatz suggests.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Okay, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'd leave as it is $$\left(\int_{0}^{x} (t^3+1)^{10} dt\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule does indeed apply here, although perhaps what is confusing you is what we set $u$ to. The chain rule states that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} \, .
$$
If $y=\left(\int_{0}^{x} (t^3+1)^{10} dt\right)^3$, then set $u$ equal to the inner function $\int_{0}^{x} (t^3+1)^{10} dt$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{d}{du}(u^3) \cdot (x^3+1)^{10} \\
&=3u^2(x^3+1)^{10} \\
&=3\left(\int_{0}^{x} (t^3+1)^{10} dt\right)^2 \cdot (x^3+1)^{10} \, .
\end{align}
So your approach was indeed correct.